# Getting request timeout when trying to connect with Gmail from browser

Tags: gmail, connection

I am unable to connect to Gmail using any browsers or any email applications. When I ping Google I am getting "Request Timeout".

I checked on other laptops and PC which are connected to the same network, using those I can connect (and also I can login) to Gmail.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Way too little information.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I suppose he has entered this many information as he doesn't know what else is necessary, please be specific to show him the good way.

Comment: what are your OS, browsers? Exactly which site do you try to ping? Do you have issue with any other sites (e.g. google.com, maps.google.com)?Do you use vpn / proxy?